# .getParentNode() is not working in case of tree with more than 1k nodes

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, ztree

I am trying to add search functionality to a tree displayed via zTree plugin.

If the search is successful then it should expand all its parent nodes and highlight the nodes.

I am using core-3.5.js version of zTree.

To implement it I am using following code:

```
{
   zTree.getNodesByParamFuzzy("name", value);
   zTree.expandNode(nodeList[i].getParentNode(), true, true, true);
}
```

This works when the tree size is <1000 nodes.

But for large # of nodes (>1k) it fails to get parent node using getParentNode() - gets stuck, may be because of large data set.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with zTree for big amount of data, around 10k, and the browser doesnt response and get freeze, I guess this plugin is not prepared to load a big amount of data once time.

I finally used lazy load for each subnode

Comment: Mr cralfaro. Could you please tell me how to used lazy load for each subnode

Comment: @Olivia i had to use dynamic loading, so every time a user clicks in a node to expand it, then call the server to render the new children